# Interactive maps with javascript

Tags: javascript, maps

i need some advices. I have to add interactive, only Europe countries map in site. So i have looking the best js library to do this. The main purpose of the map is to open page with information about that country that i have been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out AmCharts. Here's a simple demo of what seems to be what you need:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/grouped-countries-map/

It's fairly easy to learn, much easier than [D3](https://d3js.org/) (at least in my opinion) which is of course another good library for the job.